# DiscordJS Bot - How to get the message immediately before another message in a channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, chatbot

I've created a bot using DiscordJS to monitor messages. For example:

```js
client.on("message", function(message)  {
    // Do stuff
});
```

I would like to know if there is a possible way to fetch the message that was immediately sent before the current message object in the channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found a satisfactory method by doing something like this:

```js
message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: 2})
.then(messageMappings => {
let messages = Array.from(messageMappings.values());
let previousMessage = messages[1];
// do something with previous message
})
.catch(error => Logger.log("error", "Error fetching messages in channel"))
```