# Get previous message before trigger DiscordJS

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get the message sent RIGHT BEFORE each time I call the bot.

Right now I'm using:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '$test')) {
      message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 2 }).then(messages => {
    lastMessage = messages.last().content
    message.channel.send(lastMessage)

  })
}
```

The bot correctly sends the message sent before the trigger phrase if I send:

- hello
- $test

> hello

However, if I send four messages quickly:

- Welcome!
- $test
- hello
- $test

it sends:

> hello

> hello

when it should reply with `Welcome` and then `hello`.

How do I get the `content` of the message sent right before each time the bot is triggered, rather than of the second-to-last message in the channel?

Answer (score 0):

You should not try and grab the previous message, rather store the messages in order.

```js
var messages = [];

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '$test') {
        message.channel.send(messages[messages.length - 1]);
    }
    messages.push(message.content);
})
```

You are grabbing the most recent message from the channel, and that can provide unpredictable results when multiple messages are sent.

This instead logs every message in order. This will make sure that all messages will be added along with the processing to prevent discord messages loading faster than your discord bot application processing them.

There is a similar answered question to this one
[DiscordJS Bot - How to get the message immediately before another message in a channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60356882/discordjs-bot-how-to-get-the-message-immediately-before-another-message-in-a-c)